# How to get cpuinfo to show Turbo frequency?

Tags: intel, turbo-boost, cpuinfo

How do I get the frequency of my CPU when it is turbo boosted to show up in cpuinfo?

Comment: @galoget `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` shows the non-turbo maximum frequency. The duplicate candidate didn't have a suitable answer for this so I posted a new answer based on `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` and then voted to close this question as a duplicate.